# Error In installing ubuntu open Cv on ubuntu server raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: raspberrypi, opencv

My python version is

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.5
```

i am trying to install opencv on raspberry pi 3b+

i have used the following command but i always get error

> pip3 install opencv-python
>
> pip install opencv-python  Could not find
>
> Errors:
> a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions:
> ) No matching distribution found for opencv-python

i have even installed virtualenv by using the following command and tried with it .

> apt-get install virtualenv
>
> virtualenv pro
>
> source pro/bin/activate
>
> (pro) root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# pip3 install opencv-python
>
> Collecting opencv-python
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for opencv-python

Any Help ??

> My uname is
>
> Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1015-raspi2 #17-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 5 04:58:47 UTC
> 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is very simple opencv is not supported on python 3.7 so you need to build it from scratch , you guys might wanna look at my other post :

[OpenCv Building Process from Scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210770/opencv-build-process-error-on-ubuntu-raspberry-pi-3b)

Comment: Would you accept your own answer, to be easily found.