# Opencv Build Process Error on ubuntu raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: python, opencv

Hi  I Need Some Help i have tried to install opencv in python 3.7 but i found on the internet that it is not supported so you have build it from the scratch.

i followed this tutorial [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-python-source-with-opencv-and-opencv-contrib-ba95d709eb) i was able to successfully build it to 100% till i get an error on it ..

[image]

```
[100%] Building CXX object modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2                                                                                        /cv2.cpp.o
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_FileNode_at(PyObject*,                                                                                         PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:7784:47: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 7784 |         ERRWRAP2(retval = _self_->operator[](i));
      |                                               ^
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:110:5: note: in definition                                                                                         of macro ‘ERRWRAP2’
  110 |     expr; \
      |     ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_FileNode_getNode(PyObje                                                                                        ct*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:7826:54: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 7826 |         ERRWRAP2(retval = _self_->operator[](nodename));
      |                                                      ^
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:110:5: note: in definition                                                                                         of macro ‘ERRWRAP2’
  110 |     expr; \
      |     ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:166                                                                                         :
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In static member function ‘static bool PyOpenCV_Converter<                                                                                        cv::FileNode>::to(PyObject*, cv::FileNode&, const char*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:8182:20: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 8182 |             dst = *dst_;
      |                    ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_FileStorage_getFirstTop                                                                                        LevelNode(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:8250:56: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 8250 |         ERRWRAP2(retval = _self_->getFirstTopLevelNode());
      |                                                        ^
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:110:5: note: in definition                                                                                         of macro ‘ERRWRAP2’
  110 |     expr; \
      |     ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_FileStorage_getNode(PyO                                                                                        bject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:8292:54: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 8292 |         ERRWRAP2(retval = _self_->operator[](nodename));
      |                                                      ^
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:110:5: note: in definition                                                                                         of macro ‘ERRWRAP2’
  110 |     expr; \
      |     ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_cv_FileStorage_root(PyObje                                                                                        ct*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_gener                                                                                        ated_types_content.h:8401:49: warning: implicitly-declared ‘cv::FileNode& cv::Fi                                                                                        leNode::operator=(const cv::FileNode&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
 8401 |         ERRWRAP2(retval = _self_->root(streamidx));
      |                                                 ^
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:110:5: note: in definition                                                                                         of macro ‘ERRWRAP2’
  110 |     expr; \
      |     ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/cor                                                                                        e.hpp:60,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/build/modules/python_bindings_ge                                                                                        nerator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:1,
                 from /home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:32:
/home/ubuntu/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:511:                                                                                        5: note: because ‘cv::FileNode’ has user-provided ‘cv::FileNode::FileNode(const                                                                                         cv::FileNode&)’
  511 |     FileNode(const FileNode& node);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

The OS i am running [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

i am running Ubuntu Server On Raspberry pi 3b+

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/opencv-4.1.2/build$ uname -a Linux ubuntu
5.3.0-1017-raspi2 #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 16 18:25:50 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the Error i face :

[image: here is the error i face and it got terminated]

```
    c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/build.make:63: modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9267: modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/opencv-4.1.2/build$
```

Looking Forth to get some help thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I had done a lot of research and found a solution , since no one was able to answer my question i thought i might post the solution here ...

I used this automatic script for building and installing opencv ^_^ in my raspberry pi you can download it [Here](https://github.com/mdegans/nano_build_opencv)

[image]

if you get hanged during the building process you can always try the below code :

Code:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=16
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile

After compiling, you may wish to

Code:
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm /swapfile
```

Reference : [Here](https://cryptocurrencytalk.com/topic/14840-how-to-solve-g-internal-compiler-error-killed-program-cc1plus/)